# AWS API Gateway URL Query String Parameters With Square Bracket

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, aws-api-gateway

I'm making a Passthrough API Gateway using Magento 2 API to search certain products (GET Method). In this [document](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_23.html#/catalogProductRepositoryV1/catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListGet) the parameters look like this:
`searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]:name
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]:%tea%
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]:like`

When i try the endpoint API URL that given to me, it works and the result looks like this:
[image: postman]

Then I start to make the Passthrough API Gateway in AWS but unfortunately AWS API Gateway doesn't allow me to input square bracket(`[]`) in the URL Query String Parameters with message `warnings : [], errors : [Parameter name should match the following regular expression: ^[a-zA-Z0-9._$-]+$]`.
[image: aws]

I tried to deploy the API Gateway without any URL Query String Parameters and the response is that parameter is required.
[image: postman3]

Answer (score 0):

Currently the square brackets are not supported in API Gateway but you can use Percent Encoding in the URL parameters like %5B for "[".